# WCF service с аутентификацией

Tags: c#, wcf, service

Нужен пример сервиса WCF, который возвращает сообщение "пользователь не найден", если пользователь не прошел аутентификацию. Пользовательские данные записаны в xml file .

Comment: С какой частью задания у вас вопросы? Вы не понимаете, как строить WCF-сервисы? Или вы не знаете, как полученные логин-пароль сравнить с данными в XML-файле?

Comment: есть xml file  с пользовательскими данными. есть wcf сервис и  консоль-клиент . нужно чтобы при вводе логин-пароля, не состоящего в базе ,отображалась сообщение "не верный пароль/логин".

Comment: Показывайте контракты, которые уже сделали + приводите структуру xml-файла.

Answer (score 2):

Первым делом создаем WCF-сервис: [Как создать простую веб-службу WCF HTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb412178(v=vs.110).aspx)

Интерфейс сервиса:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string HasAccess(string s);
}
```

Сервис:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string HasAccess(string s)
    {
        return "Hello " + s;
    }
}
```

Затем необходимо внутри метода сервиса считать данные из XML: [Пошаговое руководство. Считывание XML-данных в набор данных](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ekw4dh3f.aspx) или так: [Практическое руководство. Чтение данных объекта из XML-файла (C# и Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms172872.aspx)

Одним из способов считываем данные. Просто Вам нужно немного почитать и разобраться с этим. И потом внутри метода читаем данные с xml, делаем необходимую проверку и готово - возвращайте что Вам нужно.

Comment: Денис, спс  за доступность)) сервис сваять способна, но не могу связать аутенфикацию клиента по логин-пароль с данными в xml file.